# Permutations with inequalities constraint

Tags: inequalities, permutation

In how many ways can I arrange the first $6$ positive integers such that this inequalities chain will hold?

$a < b > c < d < e > f$

One of these arrangements is $\{5, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3\}$, but how many is it possible to find?

Comment: Why are you interested in this question?

Comment: I found in a FB group and I tried to resolve with Mathematica, but I was not able to

Comment: The notation $a < b > c < d < e > f$ is not correct. The right math notation is $a < b , b> c , c< d , d< e,e > f$. The austerity of  5 symbols is petty.

Comment: @user64494  The same  `FullForm[a < b > c] === FullForm[a < b && b > c]`

Comment: @cvgmt: Sorry, don't unerstand: what are "the same"? The Mathematica notations are nonstandard  sometimes and this may lead to errors and misunderstandings.

Comment: @user64494  All the Mathematics books  write `a<b && b<c` to `a<b<c` . For example, `1<x<2` is the  interval of solution when we solve `(x-1)(x-2)<0`. No one will write `1<x` and `x<2`.

Comment: @cvgmt: It is impossible to look in "All the Mathematics books". See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory), especially the "Partially ordered sets" section.

Comment: @user64494  Sure, in partially ordered set, we can use chain, that is  a<b<c<d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pList = Cases[
  Permutations[Range[6], {6}], {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_} /; 
   a < b > c < d < e > f]

Length@pList
```

> 40

---

A variation using `SequenceCount`is possible with the same result.

```
SequenceCount[
 Permutations[Range[6], {6}], {{a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_}} /; 
  a < b > c < d < e > f]
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed. Now I'm asking if there is an analytical method to find that

Comment: You can post this as an addendum to your question, although such an analytical exercise is better suited for the [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) site. Or you can post a separate question on the Math SE site and put a link to this post, if it helps the explanation. Thanks.